# Missing information in News Feed

Tags: facebook, events, facebook-like, facebook-fql, feed

I am making a FQL query to get the user's News Feed. I am missing some information. E.g. when a user likes a page, I don't know what pages the user has liked and when a user is attending an event I don't know which event the user is attending.

Can anyone tell me how to get this information?

This is my query:

```
SELECT post_id, actor_id, attachment, permalink, tagged_ids, message, likes, created_time, filter_key, type, target_id FROM stream WHERE filter_key IN (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid = me() AND type = 'newsfeed') AND is_hidden = 0 ORDER BY created_time DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have just explained in another post, facebook likes do not show up in the News Feed anymore. I am sure this is due to the many "likejacking" tricks that were used in the past.

Comment: You are probably right about that. I just find it strange that the FQL query returns the likes but without any data.